# What pressure units yahoo weather api delivered when use u=f parameter

Tags: yahoo-weather-api

I was wondering what "in" stands for if we talk about pressure units? I believe that mb = mili bars = hPa. With this assumption there's something strange about it. I took 2 diffrent WOEID's for each using u=c and then u=f and results were following

1. 982.05 [mb], 29.88[in]
2. 1017.30[mb], 29.09[in]

First ratio is 32,866465863453815261044176706827

Second ratio is 34,97078033688552767273977311791

- Where this difference comes from. Does api take into consideration temperature or something else,
- What are those "in" anyway,
- Does anybody know exact formula which yahoo weather api use to conversion

Answer (score 0):

"in" is for inches of mercury (Hg) and "mb" for millibars